# Give a proof of $\forall x Fx \lor \forall x Gx \vdash \forall x (Fx \lor Gx)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> Give a
> proof of:
> $$\forall x Fx \lor \forall x Gx \vdash \forall x (Fx \lor Gx)$$

I don't know how to proof, but here is my attempt.

> 1  1) $\forall x Fx \lor \forall xGx \quad$ P
>
> 2  2) $\forall xFx \quad$ P
>
> 2  3) $Fa \quad$ 2,UI
>
> 4  4) $\forall xGx \quad$ P
>
> 4  5) $Ga \quad$ 4,UI
>
> 1 6) $Fa \lor Ga \quad$ 1,3,5 SL
>
> 1 7) $\forall x(Fx \lor Gx) \quad$ 6,UG

The rules used can be found in the following links:

- [Predicate logic rules](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwKJI9kcD_sbMm1GaHp1UzJCaHc/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1)
- [Chellas Rules](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwKJI9kcD_sbRFRsclFfczJtWmM/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1)

Comment: You cannot post $\forall x Fx$ and $\forall x Gx$ as separate premises. Nor can you use simplification (and-elimination) since the connective in your premise is $\lor$: disjunction.

Comment: I don't know other way..

Comment: @amWhy Sorry? Simplification is not used, $\rm SL$ is for "Sentential Logic". Given the premise (which is a disjunction), it is definitely admissible (and even *canonical*) to assume either disjunct, prove a shared conclusion, and infer an implication with the disjunction as the antecedent.

Comment: This proof is wrong, as you've fumbled the use of disjunction elimination. See how to do it below!

Comment: @Lord_Farin The OP is assuming each disjunct to prove two separate statements with he/she then conjoins. So I'm assuming that the OP has taken the liberty to separate the disjunction into its components, as incorrect derivations!

Comment: @amWhy No. The OP is tacitly inferring $Fa\lor Ga$ from both, then using disjunction elimination to arrive at 6 (at least, that's my reading). As I said in my answer, it's all about how much is allowed to be buried in $\rm SL$. After all, $\lor$-elimination is just an $\rm SL$ inference.

Comment: @amWhy In my reading, statement 6 falls apart in implicit statements `2 6.1 `$Fa\lor Ga$ `ADD`, `4 6.2 `$Fa\lor Ga$ `ADD` and `1 6.3`$Fa\lor Ga$ `DIL`. Note that the rule for inferring 6 is *not* $\rm DIL$ (for $\lor$-elimination), but $\rm SL$, for "follows from PropLog".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a disjunctive premiss $A \lor B$ to prove a conclusion $C$. The trick is temporarily to assume $A$ and derive $C$, then to start over, temporarily to assume $B$ and derive $C$; then we can say, either way we have $C$. This informal reasoning is captured by the propositional calculus rule of disjunction elimination, which has the following schematic pattern:

> $A \lor B\\
> \quad | \quad A\\
> \quad | \quad \ldots\\
> \quad | \quad C\\
> \quad /\\
> \quad | \quad B\\
> \quad | \quad \ldots\\
> \quad | \quad C\\
> C $

Filling in that template in the present case, a canonical natural deduction proof would go:

> $(\forall xFx \lor \forall xGx) \quad\quad\quad\textrm{Premiss}\\
> \quad | \quad \forall xFx \quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \textrm{Temporary assumption}\\
> \quad  | \quad Fa\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \textrm{Instantiate universal quantifier}\\
> \quad  | \quad (Fa \lor Ga) \quad\quad\ \ \textrm{Propositional calc}\\
> \quad  | \quad \forall x(Fx \lor Gx)\quad\ \ \textrm{Universal quantifier introduction}\\
> \quad  /\\
> \quad | \quad \forall xGx\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \textrm{New temporary assumption}\\
> \quad  | \quad Ga\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \textrm{Instantiate universal quantifier}\\
> \quad  | \quad (Fa \lor Ga) \quad\quad\ \ \textrm{Propositional calc}\\
> \quad  | \quad \forall x(Fx \lor Gx)\quad\ \ \textrm{Universal quantifier introduction}\\
> \forall x(Fx \lor Gx) \quad \quad\quad\ \ \textrm{Using initial premiss, and discharging the two temp. assumptions}
> $

NB, both subproofs have to end with the target conclusion -- compare your attempted proof which goes wrong in that respect.

Comment: Well-put and well-demonstrated. +1

Comment: But the question stated that we can use SL, so I don't need to write down all the step

Comment: But you've got to write down the basic proof structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tableau. They're often suggestive of where to go in these proofs. You start with the negation of your original formula and apply a series of simple rules which hunt for a contradiction. Look:

[image]

Can you see how your proof is related? Work backward from the $\otimes$s. I know this is very indirect but tableaux are useful tools for many problems in predicate calculus.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Why the downvote? :/

Comment: what is tableau? If you mean truth table, I can't use it.

Comment: I might put a picture in this hint soon to make in a proper answer. A tableau is a tree where each node has a set of formulea: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux.

Comment: Downvote because you are not explaining anything, not commenting on OP's proof, and pretty much disregarding anything that is specific to this problem. It's just not in any way helpful to the question at hand.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I hope that's a little better, but I actually agree with you now. I'm sorry.

Comment: If I work backward, then there are Fa and Ga. But amWhy said I cant post ∀xFx and ∀xGx as separate premises..

Comment: @puppylord: amWhy is right. It's probably better if you listen to someone other than me here. My preferred method might cause confusion :)

Comment: @Shaun Definitely enough improvement to remove my downvote. :)

Comment: @puppylord You can use each disjunct as a temporary assumptions. Then for each assumption, if you can derive a *common* statement, then the *common* statement will stand on its own. See Peter Smith's proof above! That's the correct way to use disjunction elimination.

Comment: I find this much easier to read than a truth table, it's much more informative.

Answer (score 1):

For an informal proof, yours is quite fine. Essentially, you've just left out a number of steps. Judging from the links given, you do this by appealing to $\rm SL$, which is probably short for "Sentential Logic". This abbreviates a bunch of lines which would use $\rm ADD$, $\rm DIL$ and $\rm PC$ from the "Chellas" file.

Depending on how much experience you have with propositional (= sentential) logic, this may or may not be a good idea.

In any case, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the logic of your proof (contrary to what others have said). If the use of the $\rm SL$ shorthand is admissible, I'd even go as far as saying that your derivation is the canonical, intended solution to the problem. Cheers!

---

**Added**: The objection you received from some of the other users indicates that you should be careful with your use of $\rm SL$. It is probably a good idea to briefly note what each invocation of it amounts to. But then, this is all up to personal taste. Some people dislike abbreviating anything. Others, like me, appreciate the efficiency of using $\rm SL$ in a broad fashion, so as to save time -- particularly when you have access to the completeness result for truth tables and natural deduction.

Comment: NB. If my memory serves me right, you posted this question earlier today, and it was put "on hold" pending the addition of details. In the future, please just edit a question (the link for that is on the bottom-left of your post) -- if you have addressed all the issues that caused its "holding", it will definitely be reopened.

Comment: The informal proof is quite wrong, I'm afraid. It fumbles the use of disjunction elimination: the disjuncts must be assumed in turn, and *separately* used to derive the same conclusion $C$ before you can discharge the temporary assumptions and derive the shared implication $C$. (The sentence for corrupting the youth is hemlock!)

Comment: @Peter It all depends on what is buried in the $\rm SL$. I contend that it is perfectly possible for all of the PL stuff to be buried inside it. See my comment on the question itself.

Comment: @Peter [What did I say](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555759/give-a-proof-of-forall-x-fx-lor-forall-x-gx-vdash-forall-x-fx-lor-gx#comment1182030_555886)?

Comment: Look at the OP's original attempt and he derives $Fa \lor Ga$ from two assumptions which aren't [or at least, for an application of vE, shouldn't be] in play at the same time. That's a straightforward error.

Comment: @Peter [My interpretation is different](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555759/give-a-proof-of-forall-x-fx-lor-forall-x-gx-vdash-forall-x-fx-lor-gx/555862?noredirect=1#comment1182021_555759). OP was **not** applying $\lor$-elimination.

Comment: I used DIL. Assume left first then right

Comment: A proof in Chellas's Natural Deduction system will have to use DIL, i.e. $\lor$-elimination. Given that disjunction is the premises main connective, it's the only way to extract some consequences that depend on the disjuncts.  This is what the OP says he was trying to do. He just fumbled it a bit. (OP: better, assume left, and get the desired conclusion; then start over again, assume right, and get the desired conclusion again.)

Comment: @Peter I am willing to declare a truce, but I still contend that all that OP did was to merge their use of DIL into an invocation of SL. This is *not* fumbling, it's just efficiency. I think you're underestimating the command OP has of PropLog, and that you're overly focussed on fully writing out proofs (something OP stated they didn't have to do). Also, you just didn't address the comment I referred to at all, and merely iterated your point.